# How to prevent viewstate temparing in ASP.Net page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page and have viewstate of some controls on this page.

I know it's stored in a hidden field, I want to know that how can I avoid someone from tampering the viewstate of my page ?

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [Detecting viewstate tampering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001134/detecting-viewstate-tampering) ?